# Constantly make the textbox larger

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I just started using Python PyQt5 and I am trying to make a GUI. It all works, but I have a problem with the textbox. Every time the textbox gets filled and I try to add more, it stays the same size and just adds a small scrollbar IN the textbox. What I want is for the textbox to readjust depending on the size of the text so that you can always see the text. How can I do this.

Here is my current code:

```python
#Import Module
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore 
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys

#Create Main Class
class AddToDeckWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AddToDeckWindow, self).__init__()

        #Set The UI
        self.initUI()

        #Set The GUI Position And Size
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 900, 710)

        #Set The GUI Title
        self.setWindowTitle("Add")

        #Set The GUI Icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('give_way.png'))

        #Set The Translator
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        
    def initUI(self):
        widAddToDeckWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        #Create The Text Box
        self.setCentralWidget(widAddToDeckWindow)
        textBox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(widAddToDeckWindow)
        textBox.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 200)

        #Set The Font
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        textBox.setFont(font)

#Create A Windows
def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = AddToDeckWindow()

    #Centers The Window On The Screen
    qtRectangle = win.frameGeometry()
    centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    win.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, consider that you're *not* using a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and using fixed geometries like you did, is considered bad practice and also a very **bad** idea.

For instance, in your case, if I try to resize the window to a size smaller than the bottom right corner of the text edit, it will become partially (or completely) invisible.

I *strongly* advise you against this pattern (actually, almost everybody would), as if you want to show such big margins you only need to correctly use the layout properties instead.

That said, if you want to resize a textedit according to its contents, you must implement a function that constantly checks its [`document()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop).

Then, you should choose if set the [`minimumHeight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop), or, better the [`sizeHint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop), which is used by the layout to limit its size if no more space is available. I strongly suggest you to use the latter.

```
class ResizingTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.computeHint)
        self._sizeHint = super().sizeHint()

    def computeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        height = self.document().size().height()
        height += self.frameWidth() * 2
        self._sizeHint.setHeight(max(height, hint.height()))
        self.updateGeometry()
        self.adjustSize()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self._sizeHint


class AddToDeckWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        widAddToDeckWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        #Create The Text Box
        self.setCentralWidget(widAddToDeckWindow)
        textBox = ResizingTextEdit(widAddToDeckWindow)
        textBox.setMinimumSize(500, 200)

        # this is no more necessary, as the layout will completely override it
        # textBox.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 200)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widAddToDeckWindow)

        layout.addWidget(textBox, 1, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)

        #Set The Font
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        textBox.setFont(font)
```

In case of the `minimumHeight`, use the following:

```
class ResizingTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.computeHint)

    def computeHint(self):
        height = self.document().size().height()
        height += self.frameWidth() * 2
        if height > super().sizeHint().height():
            self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        else:
            self.setMinimumHeight(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question. How do I run this because every time I try to run it, it opens a blank window with nothing in it. Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out that when I copied your code, I didn't add the __init__ function so it didn't run properly. I fixed it now. However, there is still a problem with your code. Once the text in textEdit is larger than the screen height, you can't see it anymore. Is there any way to a scroll bar OUTSIDE the textEdit and in the main window. Thanks sooo much for your help, once again!

Comment: @ThePilotDude I removed the `setMinimumHeight()` lines from the first portion of code, as I forgot it when I was checking the code, sorry about that. In this way the textedit only uses as much space as the window allows it. This is also the reason for which using `sizeHint` is the better choice, as a window should *never* try to resize itself to a size bigger than the screen.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry where did you remove `setMinimumHeight()` in the first code because every time I remove it, the textbox doesn't get any bigger?

Comment: I removed from any part in the code. Do consider that I used exactly my code, so I'm also using the grid layout with the stretch settings above.

Comment: When I remove all of them, it doesn't work anymore. Could you please edit it into your post? Thanks!

Comment: @ThePilotDude As I said, I'm using my code, I already modified it after your first comment

Comment: Having seen your new question, you are *not* using exactly my code. Look closely: I added the text edit to the **second** row of the grid, and I set a *stretch* for the first and third row; you added the text edit to the **first**, but since it has a stretch the size hint is ignored for the layout. If you want to put the text edit on top, then add it to the top as you already did and change a `setRowStretch` to (1, 1) and remove the other.

Comment: @musicmante Thanks sorry I didn't realise. Is there any way to move the  text edit to the top. I tried to use `layout.addWidget(textBox, 0, 1)`, but when I did that, the code stopped working and the textbox would no longer get larger. Sorry for all the question by the way!

Comment: @ThePilotDude I already told you: use only a `setRowStretch(0, 1)`. Please be more careful when editing other people's code: if you are not sure about what you're doing, read the documentation related to the functions used.

Comment: @musicmante my apologies I didn't see. using `setRowStretch(2, 1)` worked for me. Is there any way for me to use a horizontal layout because I want to later on create other widgets which will not be in a grid layout. Thanks once again

Comment: Also, when I enter lots of text and increase the size of the text edit by a lot and then use CTRL+A, DELETE, the text edit stays as a large size, and doesn't shrink back to it's normal size. How would I get around this?

Comment: Sorry, in the last comment I meant `setRowStretch(1, 1), as per the comment before that; if you're adding the widget on top of the grid, you should set the stretch for the *second* row (1), not the third. If you want to add other widgets on the side of the current things might change, and that depends on the situation, but at that point I'd say that the whole auto-resizing makes even less sense than it already does: there's no *real* benefit in using only part of the available space with a constantly growing widget, especially when other widgets exist. I'd suggest you to avoid all that.

Comment: @musicmante I thank you so much for help. Last thing, how would I add a scrollbar for the window, not textEdit if the text edit gets longer than the window size. Thanks so much

Comment: And how would I add a second textbox that also self resizes

Comment: @ThePilotDude this is my last comment, as extended discussion should be avoided in comments and this is becoming off topic. You can't add a scroll bar for the window, you can only use a QScrollArea as central widget, but I strongly suggest you to avoid it, as there are very few cases for which using a scroll area for all the contents of an interface is a good idea, especially for a main window, and even more importantly if some widgets are scrollable; also, this autoresizing concept will probably *not* work anymore. As said, you should avoid it entirely. About the delete issue, see the update.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. Thank you soooooo much! I wish there were more people like you on stack overflow!